# Flex release build issue (AIR application)

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have an issue on exported build release from Flash Builder 4.6. The case is when I run it on the IDE(Flash Builder 4.6) it works fine, no issues encountered, it never crashed but when I exported it for a release build and run, it crashes to a certain module/view. The view/module where the AIR app crashes has multiple remote object calls (minimum of 5). I have noticed that when requesting multiple remote object calls(like 5 remote calls at a time) it crashes. Is the remote object causes the crash? Please help me out on this guys, any idea will be much appreciated.

Thanks
 Glen

Comment: wrap a try catch around the suspect code and trace out the error in the catch statement

Comment: Crash = app closes, no error prompts. I'll try the "try catch" method. Thanks for the reply by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's a security issue that you worked around when invoking the application from the ide. By default, Flash Builders working directories are marked as "secure", so you don't get any security issues. But when working on the live system, you might need to have a corssdomain policy.

Also: i suggest to use the Thunderbolt logger with the logging framework. This allows you to get log informations straight into your browser's console.

Comment: It is an AIR application, there is no browser involved

Comment: As Neil said; an AIR Application does not have any cross domain issues.  I'm not quite sure what "By default, Flash Builder Working directories are marked as secure" means.  When loading a SWF in a browser using a local file system URL--and not from a web server--that SWF is not bound to cross domain issues.  But, when dealing with an AIR application no cross domain is needed because there is no need to work around a web browsers security sandbox.